# Is Hive and Impala integration possible?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, impala

Is `Hive` and `Impala` integration possible?

After data processing in hive i want to store result data in impala for better read, is it possible?

If yes can you please share one example.

Answer (score 2):

Impala uses the HIVE metastore to read the data. Once you have a table created in hive, it is possible to read the same and query the same using Impala. All you need is to refresh the table or trigger INVALIDATE METADATA in impala to read the data.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Both hive and impala, do not store any data. The data is stored in the HDFS location and hive an impala both are used just to visualize/transform the data present in the HDFS.

So yes, you can process the data using hive and then read it using impala, considering both of them have been setup properly. But since impala needs to be refreshed, you need to run the invalidate metadata and refresh commands

Answer (score 0):

Hive and impala are two different query engines. Each query engine is unique in terms of its architecture as well as performance. We can use hive metastore to get metadata and running query using impala. The common usecase is to connect impala/hive from tableau. If we are visualizing hive from tableau, we can get the latest data without any work around. If we keep on loading the data continuously, metadata will be updated as well. Impala does not aware of those changes. So we should run metadata invalidate query by connecting impalad to refresh its state and sync with the latest info available in metastore. So that user will get the same results as hive when the run the same query from tableau using impala engine.

There is no configuration parameter available now to run this invalidation query periodically. This [blog](https://hadoopjournal.wordpress.com/2015/12/06/auto-execution-of-validate-metadata-in-impala/) reads well to execute meta data invalidation query through oozie scheduler periodically to handle such problems, Or simply we can set up a cronjob from the server itself.